# Obtener el valor maximo de un campo, a partir de una serie de registros. MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

La consulta es la siguiente, se tienen 2 tablas:

```
Pagos                             
-idPago                                
-idCliente                             
-fechaEnQuePaga                        
-fechaVencimiento
```

```
Cliente
-idCliente
-nombre
-apellidoPaterno
-apellidoMaterno
-correo
```

`idCliente` es llave foránea.
Suponiendo que las tablas tienen los siguientes datos:

Tabla Pagos:

```
1 | 1 | 2018-02-23 | 2018-03-23
2 | 2 | 2018-02-23 | 2018-05-23
3 | 2 | 2018-02-23 | 2018-06-23
4 | 1 | 2018-04-23 | 2018-07-23
```

Tabla Clientes:

```
1 | Daniel | Sosa  | Estrada | sosa@algo.com
2 | Juan   | Casas | Sola    | sola@algo.com
```

Y quiero obtener los datos del cliente, seguido de los datos de su pago pero, con al fecha de vencimiento más lejana, esperando obtener:

```
1 | Daniel | Sosa  | Estrada | 2018-04-23 | 2018-07-23
2 | Juan   | Casas | Sola    | 2018-02-23 | 2018-06-23
```

Tengo un query, que se asemeja pero no me da los resultados esperados:

```
SELECT
    cliente.idcliente,
    nombre,
    apellidoPaterno,
    apellidoMaterno,
    fechaEnQuePaga,
    fechavencimiento
FROM cliente, pagos
WHERE (cliente.idcliente = pagos.idcliente)
GROUP BY idcliente;
```

Resultado:

```
1 | Daniel | Sosa  | Estrada | 2018-02-23 | 2018-03-25
2 | Juan   | Casas | Sola    | 2018-02-23 | 2018-05-23
```

Noté que si agrego `MAX()` me localiza la fecha a vencer más lejana, pero no muestra su fecha de pago correspondiente:

```
SELECT
    cliente.idcliente,
    nombre,
    apellidoPaterno,
    apellidoMaterno,
    fechaEnQuePaga,
    MAX(fechavencimiento)
FROM cliente, pagos
WHERE (cliente.idcliente = pagos.idcliente)
GROUP BY idcliente;
```

Resultado:

```
1 | Daniel | Sosa  | Estrada | 2018-02-23 | 2018-07-25
2 | Juan   | Casas | Sola    | 2018-02-23 | 2018-06-23
```

La fecha de pago no corresponde a la de la fila.

Agradezco su respuesta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Las funciones ventana son ideales para este tipo de consulta, pero MySQL no las tiene :(

Lo que puedes hacer es un join normal (o un left join si es posible que un cliente no tenga pagos), pero agregarle una subconsulta correlativa que filtra los resultados por `MAX(fechavencimiento)`:

```
select c.idcliente,
       c.nombre,
       c.apellidoPaterno,
       c.apellidoMaterno,
       p.fechaEnQuePaga,
       p.fechavencimiento
  from cliente c
  left join pagos p
    on p.idcliente = c.idcliente
   and p.fechavencimiento = (select max(p2.fechavencimiento)
                               from pagos p2
                              where p2.idcliente = p.idcliente)
```

Advertencia: Si un cliente puede tener valores `fechavencimiento` duplicados en la tabla `pagos`, entonces existe la posibilidad que esta consulta te devuelva más de un registro por cliente.

Answer (score 3):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT
    C.idcliente,
    C.nombre,
    C.apellidoPaterno,
    C.apellidoMaterno,
    P.fechaEnQuePaga,
    P.fechavencimiento,
FROM
    cliente C
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            P2.idCliente,
            P2.fechaEnQuePaga,
            P2.fechaVencimiento
        FROM
            pagos P2
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT
                    idCliente,
                    MAX(fechaVencimiento) AS fechaVencimiento
                FROM pagos
                GROUP BY idCliente
            ) P1 ON P1.idCliente = P2.idCliente AND P1.fechaVencimiento = P2.fechaVencimiento
    ) P ON P.idCliente = c.idCliente
```

Veamos:

- En primer lugar con la subconsulta más interna cuyo alias es `P1` obtenemos la máxima `fechaVencimiento` por cliente
- Luego con la subconsulta `P2` obtenemos el o los registros cuyos pagos correspondan a la máxima `fechaVencimiento` de `P1`. **Importante**, si tuvieras varios registros para un cliente con la misma `fechaVencimiento` (en tu ejemplo pareciera que no ocurre) deberías agregar un anidamiento más para "decidir" con cual fila te quedas, siempre que lo que esperas es tener una única fila por cliente.
- Por último hacemos el `JOIN` final entre `clientes` y `pagos`, usa un `LEFT` si no quieres perder de vista aquellos clientes que no tienen pagos o un `INNER` si los quieres eliminar de la consulta.

Esta es una solución bastante básica usando SQL plano, me imagino que en **MySql** hay formas mejores de resolverlo.

Comment: Muy bien entendido, utilizar tu explicación detallada es un extra.

Este tipo de comentarios ayudan a fortalecer aún mas temas de SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza INNER JOIN con ORDER BY

```
SELECT c.idCliente,c.nombre,c.apellidoPaterno,c.apellidoMaterno,p.fechaEnQuePaga,p.fechaVencimiento
  FROM Pagos p
INNER JOIN Clientes c ON p.idCliente = c.idCliente
ORDER BY p.fechaVencimiento DESC
```

De esta manera lograras obtener la union de tus filas y podras filtrar por el campo que tu quieras en el orden que le especifiques (ASC (ascendente), DESC (descendente))

Comment: Esto devolverá 4 registros en vez de 2.

Answer (score 1):

La query que se asemeja es porque cuando agrupa toma el último valor del group, por loq que solo tendrías que agregarle un GROUP BY,

```
 SELECT 
   cliente.idcliente, 
   nombre, 
   apellidoPaterno, 
   apellidoMaterno,
   fechaEnQuePaga,
   fechavencimiento,
FROM cliente,pagos
WHERE (cliente.idcliente=pagos.idcliente)
GROUP BY idcliente
ORDER BY fechavencimiento ASC;
```

Si esta no te funciona cambia el ASC por el DESC y vuelve a probar.

Tienes que tener cuidado con esto, si lo importas a un mysql que tenga el constraint ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY marcara error

como bien mencionan esto quedaría con inner join así

```
 SELECT 
   cliente.idcliente, 
   nombre, 
   apellidoPaterno, 
   apellidoMaterno,
   fechaEnQuePaga,
   fechavencimiento,
FROM cliente
INNER JOIN pagos
ON cliente.idcliente=pagos.idcliente
GROUP BY idcliente
ORDER BY fechavencimiento ASC;
```

Comment: Esto es peligroso. [La documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) es bien claro de que cuando se usa `GROUP BY` de esta manera, no hay garantías de qué valor va a usar en este caso para `fechaEnQuePaga` y `fechavencimiento`, y que tratar de usar `ORDER BY` para controlar esto no es válido. Si funciona, es accidentalmente.

Comment: Nunca había leído esta parte de la documentación, gracias por la aclaración, de cualquier forma dejo la respuesta para quien tenga duda no piense en esto como una opción